# Joyal's topos in which $[0,1]$ fails to be compact

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, lo.logic, topos-theory, constructive-mathematics

Some time around 1977, André Joyal constructed a topos (actually a locale, i.e., a localic topos, necessarily [non-spatial](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424356/examples-of-statements-that-are-valid-in-every-spatial-topos)) in which the closed unit interval $[0,1]$ fails to be compact.  There are only two places that I know of in which the topos in question is described or discussed:

- very briefly, in a postscript at the end (p.301) of Fourman & Hyland's paper “Sheaf Models for Analysis” (p.280–301 in Fourman, Mulvey & Scott, *Applications of Sheaves (Durham 1977)* (1979 Springer LNM **753**));
- and in a somewhat more detailed way as example D.4.7.13 (p.1026–1028 in vol.2) in Johnstone's *Sketches of an Elephant: A Topos Theory Compendium* (Cambridge 2002).

(Johnstone describes the topos in question as the classifying topos of the theory of an open cover of $[0,1]$ such that each finite subcover has Lebesgue measure $<\frac{1}{2}$.  The crucial point is that the object representing the interval $[0,1]$ is this topos comes from $\textbf{Set}$, i.e., is the constant sheaf with value $[0,1]$.  Even if Johnstone's description is much more lengthy than Fourman & Hyland's 15-line postscript, it is still more an extended exercise than a full description.)

Since Johnstone does not give any other reference than Fourman & Hyland (and in particular, nothing by Joyal himself), I guess Joyal himself never published anything on the subject.  Still, since this example is rather surprising and highly instructive, one might hope that it has been studied, or at least described, in greater detail, in the 20 years since Johnstone's account.  So:

**Question:** Are there other descriptions, hopefully with even more details than Johnstone gives, of the topos in question?  Has it been further studied somewhere (e.g., along the lines of what real analysis looks like in this topos)?

Comment: I would be interested in knowing whether the unit interval is countable in this topos, i.e. whether there is an injection from [0,1] to $\mathbb{N}$.  There are fairly strong classical systems in which the unit interval is countable in this way.

Comment: @SamSanders I thought you couldn't have an injection from $[0,1]$ into $\mathbb{N}$ in a topos since that makes equality in $[0,1]$ decidable, which then allows you to run Cantor's diagonal argument in the interval.

Comment: @JamesHanson But in $\textbf{Set}$ equality of the _set_ $[0, 1]$ is in fact decidable, and $\textbf{Set}$ is a topos.

Comment: Cantor's argument shows that if $[0,1]$ has decidable equality there is no surjection $\mathbb{N} \to [0,1]$ but there can still be an injection. The main topos theory example is realizability on infinite time Turing machines.

Comment: @aws It's pretty clear there is an injection $\mathbb{N}\to[0,1]$. Did you mean something else?

Comment: I haven't looked at the references but could this be the localic topos associated to [amoeba forcing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amoeba_order) (with something milder than the double-negation topology, of course).

Comment: Sorry, I meant $[0,1] \to \mathbb{N}$ for the injection.

Comment: But actually I think it should be an injection $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ - I'm not sure if it extends to the real numbers.

Comment: @aws Right, I was getting confused with the fact that you can prove that no topos has a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $[0,1]$.

Comment: @JamesHanson I guess so if you would have enough AC (to go from the injection to a sequence), but perhaps also independence of premises is needed?

Comment: @aws Just to confirm, yes, Andrej's [paper](https://bit.ly/3qQ9lxj) shows that the realizability topos built using ITTMs has an injection $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}\hookrightarrow\mathbb{N}$, but his argument is easily adapted to $\mathbb{R}\hookrightarrow\mathbb{N}$. (See Footnote 10 of [this survey of mine](https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.00948) for a somewhat self-contained argument.) — Only in the trivial topos there can be a bijection $\mathbb{N}\cong[0,1]$. A topos containing a surjection $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ has [recently been found](https://youtu.be/4CBFUojXoq4) by Andrej and James Henson.

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt I'm always pleased to see someone mention a result I had something to do with but I should point out that I am not the beloved creator of *The Muppets* James Henson, unfortunately enough.

Comment: To the OP: Are you specifically requesting more detailed information about this particular topos, or a concrete description of any topos in which $[0,1]$ is not compact?

Comment: @MorganRogers I'm aware that the Fourman-Hyland paper contains a description of another (localic) topos in which $[0,1]$ is not compact, which is easier to understand. But they say (in the footnote) that their models are “primitive in comparison to Joyal's elegant construction”, and I don't really understand why, or what makes Joyal's topos better (or at least more “elegant”), so that's part of my question.